# Is there a memory efficient way to convert input stream encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream

I'm reading a potentially massive CSV file from Google Cloud Storage using a http client. Once i've got the CSV file, I need to upload it to another bucket, and load the data into a BigQuery table. Unfortunately, the file that i'm downloading is encoded in UTF-16, and BigQuery only supports UTF-8. I need a way to convert the data from UTF-16 to UTF-8. I know that I could simply read the data from the http response input stream as UTF-16, then write it to a new input stream as UTF-8 like so:

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent());
String csv = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

However, given that the CSV file has no maximum size and has the potential to be really big, i'd like to avoid reading it into memory if possible. I need the end product of this process to be an InputStream so as to not break the contract of the interface.

I've thought about using a BufferedReader to read the input stream one line at a time and convert the encoding, but i'm not really sure if that's any more efficient once it's been converted to a new input stream.

Is there any way to convert from UTF-16 contents in an input stream to UTF-8 contents in a memory efficient way?

Comment: Use `IOUtils.copy(InputStream, Writer, Charset)`. You can just redirect the data from input stream to the output stream

Comment: @maklas thanks for the suggestion, but as I say I need the output of this process to be an input stream, not a writer/output stream.

Comment: @Ben_Green. Ok gotcha. You need to decode bytes as utf16 characters and then encode them as utf8. Then this might work. Double-wrapping input stream.

```java
InputStreamReader utf16Reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
ReaderInputStream utf8IS = new ReaderInputStream(utf16Reader, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: @maklas that looks like a decent shout. I assume the InputStreamReader doesn't read the input stream into memory? If you put an answer, i'll upvote it :)

Comment: @Ben_Green. Of course it does. How else would it decode and encode it. But it doesn't read entire stream and puts it into a string. It probably just reads by small chunks of 8 kb, processing each of the chunk in a while loop. So it won't load all the data into your memory. Your ram and garbage collector will be happy.

Comment: @maklas Yep, that's what I meant sorry. Thanks. Feel free to add as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already use `commons.io` library. This might be just what you're looking for:

```java
InputStreamReader utf16Reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
ReaderInputStream utf8IS = new ReaderInputStream(utf16Reader, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Which double wraps `is` into `utf16`-decoding reader and then into `utf8` encoding byte-stream